# XElement Replacement when Child Elements and Value Exist

Tags: c#, xml, linq, replace, linq-to-xml

I have some Xml that I am trying to change the name of the XElement on. The XElement contains both child elements and a value similar to this

```
<parent>
  Hi I am a value <a href="link">link</a>
</parent>
```

I tried using the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545349/change-the-name-of-an-xelement-in-linq-to-xml) but i can only copy either the elements or the value. Setting the elements first and then the value wipes out the elements.

```
<newparent>
  Hi I am a value link
</newparent>
```

Copying the value and then elements duplicates the element text

```
<newparent>
  Hi I am a value link <a href="link">link</a>
</newparent>
```

String manipulation of the value itself escapes all of the brackets.

```
<newparent>
  Hi I am a value link &lt;a href="link"&gt;link&lt;/a&gt;
</newparent>
```

Does someone know of a way to achieve the result of copying the value and elements over to the newly created element correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question correctly, you want all the child nodes copied to a new parent with a different name. If so, use the `Nodes()` method.

```
XElement parent = XElement.Parse("<parent>Hi I am a value <a href=\"link\">link</a></parent>");
var newparent = new XElement("newparent", parent.Nodes());
```